# How to solve the display exception when i use vim+tmux in xshell

Tags: vim, tmux, xshell

i use tmux + vim in xshell, When I use it will cause display exception

```
set laststatus=2
```

- use vim without tmux in xshell, it works ok
- use vim + tmux in xshell without use statusline, it works ok
- use in putty or mobaxterm, it works ok

tmux version

```
tmux 2.9a
```

vim version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 11 2019 09:13:18)
Included patches: 1-1517
```

server version

```
Linux version 3.13.0-32-generic (buildd@kissel) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFlAQ.png)

Comment: This is a non-standard status line. Is this lightline plugin? Any special setup for it? What's about standard status line? Is it broken too?

Comment: i use  itchyny/lightline.vim
and my vimrc is:
https://github.com/xyrh/vimrc.git

Comment: when i not use plugin, under set laststatus=2. it looks work ok

Comment: If the issue doesn't persist without the plugin then this is probably a better question to raise with the author of the plugin.

Comment: When I use dynamic parameters in statusline such as %p, Keep searching for display exception,  not use plugin
```
set statusline=%<%f\
set statusline+=%w%h%m%r
set statusline+=\ [%{&ff}/%Y]
set statusline+=\ [%{getcwd()}]
set statusline+=\ %p%%
```
if i not use set statusline+=\ %p%%, it works ok

Comment: set statusline=%<%F\ %w%h%m%r%=[%{&ff}/%Y/%{&enc}]
final, i use this and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem that has troubled me for three years.

```
.bashrc:

export TERM=screen-256color

.tmux.conf:

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Comment: Better not to do this in bashrc: most terminal emulators set TERM appropriately.